# Сделать снимок камеры

Tags: java, android

Ошибка при попытке снятия фотографии, вот весь код класса, который отлично показывает превьюшку в `surface`, но не фотографирует.

```
public class CameraFront extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Camera.PictureCallback, Camera.PreviewCallback {

    private Camera sCamera;
    private View sView;
    private Context sContext;
    private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
    private SurfaceView sPreview;

    public CameraFront(Context Context, View View)
    {
        super(Context);
        this.sView = View;
        this.sContext = Context;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
         sCamera = openFrontFacingCameraFroyo();
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)         
         sCamera = Camera.open(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);  

        sPreview = (SurfaceView) sView.findViewById(R.id.CameraFront); 
        sHolder = sPreview.getHolder();
        sHolder.addCallback(this);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
         sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);  



        sCamera.takePicture(null, null, null, this); /// ЗАВИСАЕТ И Camera server died! ICamera died     Error 100
    }   


    public Camera openFrontFacingCameraFroyo() {
        Camera camera = null;

        try {
            Class<?> cameraClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera");
            Object cameraInfo = null;
            Field field = null;
            int cameraCount = 0;
            Method getNumberOfCamerasMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "getNumberOfCameras" );
            if ( getNumberOfCamerasMethod != null ) {
                cameraCount = (Integer) getNumberOfCamerasMethod.invoke( null, (Object[]) null );
            }
            Class<?> cameraInfoClass = Class.forName("android.hardware.Camera$CameraInfo");
            if ( cameraInfoClass != null ) {
                cameraInfo = cameraInfoClass.newInstance();
            }
            if ( cameraInfo != null ) {
                field = cameraInfo.getClass().getField( "facing" );
            }
            Method getCameraInfoMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "getCameraInfo", Integer.TYPE, cameraInfoClass );
            if ( getCameraInfoMethod != null && cameraInfoClass != null && field != null ) {
                for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
                    getCameraInfoMethod.invoke( null, camIdx, cameraInfo );
                    int facing = field.getInt( cameraInfo );
                    if ( facing == 1 ) {
                        try {
                            Method cameraOpenMethod = cameraClass.getMethod( "open", Integer.TYPE );
                            if ( cameraOpenMethod != null ) {
                                camera = (Camera) cameraOpenMethod.invoke( null, camIdx );
                            }
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch ( ClassNotFoundException e        ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch ( NoSuchMethodException e         ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch ( NoSuchFieldException e          ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch ( IllegalAccessException e        ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch ( InvocationTargetException e     ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch ( InstantiationException e        ) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch ( SecurityException e             ) {e.printStackTrace();}

        if ( camera == null ) {

            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return camera;
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {  

     try
     {      
      sCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);    
     }
     catch (IOException e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams settings = sPreview.getLayoutParams();
     sCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90); 
     settings.height = 100;
     settings.width = 100;
     sPreview.setLayoutParams(settings);
     sCamera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        System.out.println("LOG Changed");  
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
        System.out.println("LOG surfaceDestroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        System.out.println("LOG TAKE"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("LOG onPreviewFrame");   
    }   
}
```

Как я уже пометил в коде после `takepicture` виснет и `ERROR 100`.

Comment: чего-то не хватает... может быть стактрейса?

Comment: Был бы признателен если бы вы,нормально объяснили в чем ошибка.

Comment: Сейчас достану свой хрустальный шар, погадаю на дохлой мыши ,чайной гуще, призову демонов, и скажу, где ошибка. Никто не знает, где у вас ошибка. Выложите стактрейс, тогда попробуем помочь.